# separate styles for separate module in Angular 5

Tags: css, angular, module, bootstrap-4

My project has two main parts. One for public web pages and the other for admin control panel. Each of them has separate CSS and javascript files for their template.

If I define all CSS and js files in index.html, all files load in the first meet of the web page, and also maybe have a conflict between CSS classes.

How can I handle this problem?

**app.component:**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**app-routing.module:**

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";

import { FirstComponent } from './first/first.component';


const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'first', component: FirstComponent },
  {
    path: 'controlpanel',
    loadChildren: 'app/control-panel/control-panel.module#ControlPanelModule'
  },
  {
    path: 'publicpanel',
    loadChildren: 'app/public-panel/public-panel.module#PublicPanelModule'
  }
];
```

each module has its submodules. Can I separate their styles?

Comment: Why not define the CSS on a per-component basis?

Comment: you mean that add css files in styleUrls list?

Comment: Yes, give each component its own CSS file, and load that in the styleUrls list, that way you won't get conflicts

Comment: how about js files. for example if I use a bootstrap template, it have some js files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. We can disable or enable css files in component.

```
document.styleSheets[2].disabled = false;
```

or

```
document.styleSheets[2].disabled = true;
```

that's it.

Comment: This is very helpful, but there is one problem we have to find the css from arrays that we need to disable

Answer (score 1):

Use sass and create a class flag for public and admin **components** 
like this

theme/_public.scss

```
.public{ 
  label { 
    color:red;
  }
}
```

theme/_admin.scss

```
.admin { 
  label {
    color:green;
  }
}
```

and this in main style.scc

```
@import "theme/_public.scss";
@import "theme/_admin.scss";
```

this is much better for app performance you will have one style file with public and admin pages style

[stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aq1hzh)

Comment: Muhammad Albarmawi, with your method, both styles loaded in first meet

Comment: Yes all the style will be bundle with one file but the will not going conflict because class flag

Comment: just look to each flag give diffrent color for label elemnt