# CSS scope only to an entire module in Angular

Tags: css, angular, module, lazy-loading

I am doing a lazy-loading to a module, and I want to load a CSS file when that module is loaded. The CSS file should only affect that particular module.

I can't put it on *styles.css* because it would affect the other modules.

Thanks!

Comment: Some solution can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51360813/separate-styles-for-separate-module-in-angular-5 We can disable or enable css files in component.

Comment: If appropriate, you might just use a shell component that wraps your other module components. The shell styles should propagate to the children.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have manage to add customer style for each module by create a style file for each module and add this style file in the component stylr list

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.module.scss' , './app.component.scss' ],
})
```

or you can use scss impot inside the component style file

*app.component.scss*

```css
@import './app.module.scss';
```